# How to extract HTML's <td> tag data using regex in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I trying to read Username and Password from an Email using Java
It is returning mail content in html format and I just wanted to extract Username and Password which is present under `<td>` tag. Below is my HTML code snippet -

```
<table width="200">
   <tbody>
     <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Your Account Details:</td>
     </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>EmailId:</td>
        <td><a class="moz-txt-link-abbreviated" href="mailto:jainish.m.kapadia@trimantra.net">jainish.m.kapadia@trimantra.net</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Password:</td>
         <td>C3mRXh+|n#1J</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: `(<td>)(.*)(<\\/td>)` this will give you the content inside the td tags. you will need to use the 2nd group. you will not get the actual email, because this one is inside <a> tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please don't try to parse HTML with RegEx,
for a detailed answer on why you shouldn't try this see this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3003852).

You can use [jsoup](https://jsoup.org) for parsing your HTML Strings like this:

```
String html = "<html><head><title>First parse</title></head>"
  + "<body><p>Parsed HTML into a doc.</p></body></html>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

Element content = doc.getElementById("content");
Elements links = content.getElementsByTag("a");
for (Element link : links) {
  String linkHref = link.attr("href");
  String linkText = link.text();
}
```

jsoup also offers methods for hierarchical navigation like

```
siblingElements();
nextElementSibling();
```

and so on.

Comment: Thanks, my problem got resolved.  Jsoup is the more convenient way rather then using Regex to find the matches. even though I found the regex only for password like `<td>Password:<.*?td>([^<]+)<td>(.+)<.*?td>`

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code snippet:

```
String str = "your html";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(<td>(.*?)<\\/td>)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
```

This will give you back all the `<td>` tag. Now you can loop through the `matcher` and get your required string.

Comment: this does not give the exact email because the email is inside <a> tag. i know its not what he asked but might be worth mentioning

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Thank you for appreciation.